# C++ performance - reading numbers from a file

Tags: c++, performance

I have a file in which are numbers divided by spaces (i.e. matrix). For xample:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

I would like to read these numbers and store them in two dimensional array `int**`. I've found numerous solutions how to solve this, but I don't know, which of these gives the best performance.
Furthermore I would like to ask, if there is possibility to read the mentioned file in paralell.

EDIT: The data I want to read is much more bigger (I included the data only as an example), I would like store big matrices, possibly with rows of different lengths into the mentioned array for further manipulation

Comment: Can you give what you have already done ? Nobody can compare solutions without having it!

Comment: I don't want to compare my solutions, I would like to know the generally best way to do this.

Comment: It's off-topic for SO... and just to give an indication for reading in paralell, I think it's possible, be divinding your file in equal parts (using seek for example to navigate in file) you can give each part to a thread and fill your array

Comment: Is the data you want to read small ? The exampel you mention is tiny and it's pointless to optimize for such tiny data quantities. Be more specific.

Comment: The data I want to read is much more bigger (I included the data only as an example), I would like store big matrices, possibly with rows of different lengths into the mentioned array for further manipulation.

Comment: @P.Brown you should mention this in your question.

Comment: You can only read from one location on the disk at a time, so concurrent reading of a single file is largely pointless. (Also, subdividing a text file of numbers requires you to read the entire file first.)

Comment: If you want performance, use a binary format, not text. Otherwise, most of your time reading will be spent parsing numbers.

Comment: I don't think there is a "generally best" way to do this. I feel that programming is about first coming up with a solution that works, which usually takes a long time, then proceeding to identify problems in the implementation, such as inefficiencies (inefficient traversal of a 2D array in your case) or inflexibilities (inability to specify the size of the 2D array at run-time in your case).

Answer (score 0):

For the best performance to read the file in paralell, you can use couple copies of file. And you can use row index to quickly read particular row.